# How to handle request from $_POST where no Symfony form is defined on the request, without searching form classname?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.3

How can I handle request data from the `$_POST` data itself. I mean if I try to handle the form like this:  `$form->handleRequest($request);`, Symfony would try to get the data from `$_POST['form_classname']`, but I want to fill my form class straight from base `$_POST` variables.

Actually I want to handle the information from the outer site. And I have to develop something like an API. But without authorization, tokens, etc...

So I decided to build the form with some properties I need. After validation the form might do some logic.

Here is an example of `$_POST` I have to handle

```
Function=TransResponse&RESULT=0&RC=00&AUTHCODE=745113
```

As you can see, there is no form name in request. The `$form->handleRequest($request);` works only if the request was like an

```
[form_name][Function]=TransResponse&[form_name][RESULT]=0&[form_name][RC]=00&[form_name][AUTHCODE]=745113
```

But I can't change the request format.

Comment: Not sure your question is totally clear. Everything should be available in `$request` So why do you want to use `$_POST`

Comment: Try `$request->get('yourProperty')` Do you have non mapped field ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Actually, I want to use $request. But I want to use handleRequest method with the data stored in base $_POST, not $_POST[form_name]

Comment: @DylanDelobel `$request->get('yourProperty')` works like a charm. But the form doesn't handle the $request data. Because it tries to search form_name int the $_POST and fill my form with the $_POST[form_name] that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put in your form class

```
/** @inheritdoc */
function getBlockPrefix() {
    return '';
}
```

Here is the information about this method [Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Form/AbstractType.html#method_getBlockPrefix)

Answer (score 0):

Use

- `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamed('')`
- `$this->get('form.factory.)->createNamedBuilder('')`

to create a Form or FormBuilder respectively that uses the whole `$_POST`/`$_GET` array for its parameters.

Example:

```
/**
 * @Route("/testRoute")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function testAction(Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('', FormType::class, null, ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->add('text', TextType::class)
        ->setMethod('GET')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        return new Response($form['text']->getData());
    }

    return new Response('<a href="?text=123">Submit me</a>');
}
```